# Sending a GET command every 10 seconds does not request the backend

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

In my service:

```
    public sendUpdate(idBombeamento:number): Observable<any>{

      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
      });    
    
      //console.log(headers.get('Authorization'));
      const requestOptions = { headers: headers };
    
      return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/${idBombeamento}`,requestOptions);     
  
    }
```

In my component:

```
import { catchError, interval, map, Observable, switchMap, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class BombeamentoComponent implements OnInit{
  protected idBombeamento:number=0;

 constructor(
    private bombService:BombeamentoService,
    private routeA: ActivatedRoute,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private http:HttpClient){
      this.routeA.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.idBombeamento = params['id'];     
      });
  }
```

How can I make a GET request every 10 seconds to update my component's data?

Dependencias:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
```

I tested it in several ways, but the GET command is not sent to the backend every 10 seconds, it always gets the response from the first request:

```
ngOnInit():void{
    setInterval(() => {
      this.bombService.sendUpdate(this.idBombeamento).subscribe({
        next: (res)=>{
          this.retornoChamado = res;
          this.openSnackBar1("Enviado com sucesso!","",false);
          console.log(this.retornoChamado);          
        },
        error:(e)=>console.log(e),
      });
    }, 10000);
}
```

```
ngOnInit():void{
interval(10000).subscribe(res=>{this.bombService.sendUpdate(this.idBombeamento).subscribe((res2)=>{
  console.log("passou");
  console.log(res2);
})});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you please try like this

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

ngOnInit(): void {
  interval(10000)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => this.bombService.sendUpdate(this.idBombeamento))
    )
    .subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("Received response:", res);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: It gives a console log every 10 seconds but it doesn't go through the backend. Always have the same value.

Comment: Subscribe is deprecated;

Comment: it is a correct answer and subscribe() is not deprecated.

Comment: for me it appears deprecated:

Comment: try to use subscribe with explicit `next` and `error` callbacks, like this: 
.subscribe({
   next: (res) => console.log("Received response:", res),
   error: (error) => console.error("Error:", error)
})

Comment: It's as if this request was already in a browser cache and was no longer executed!

Answer (score 0):

The GET request was being cached by the browser, we have to put it in the HEADERS so as not to have a cache, here is an example of headers:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`,
'Cache-Control':  'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Expires': '0'
});
```